# Attributes in method override

Tags: c#, overriding

I have a base class with a method. Derived classes just need to decorate that method with an attribute (different for each derived class) and leave the body untouched.

I did something like

**Base class**

```
public virtual int Method1()
{
    // body
}

public virtual int Method2()
{
    // body
}
```

**Derived class A**

```
[AttributeA(ParameterName = "AName", CommandName = "ACommand")]
public override int Method1()
{
    return base.Method1();
}

[AttributeA(ParameterName = "AnotherName", CommandName = "AnotherCommand")]
public override int Method2()
{
    return base.Method2();
}
```

**Derived class B**

```
[AttributeB(ParameterName = "BName", CommandName = "BCommand")]
public override int Method1()
{
    return base.Method1();
}

[AttributeB(ParameterName = "BnotherName", CommandName = "BnotherCommand")]
public override int Method2()
{
    return base.Method2();
}
```

and it works but it doesn't seem really pretty to me, the main reason being that it leaves the client free to override the body of the method, which is something I'd rather avoid, and it's also tedious to just repeat `return base.Method();`.

Is there a cleaner approach to solve this kind of problem? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Can you just apply the attribute to the class instead? It would help if you'd provide more context about what the attribute is there for.

Comment: @JonSkeet as I wrote, the attribute would be different for every derived class. The base class is an mvc controller and I use the attributes in order to provide some kind of authorization checks. Those are customs attributes and there's one for every derived controller. I'll add an example.

Comment: I don't see how that changes what I'm suggesting... why can't you apply `AttributeA` to class A, and `AttributeB` to class B, rather than putting it on the individual method?

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah sorry, I thought you were talking about applying it to the base class. I cannot do that because the attribute takes some parameters which are different from method to method (in the same class). Improved examples to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no other way to do that.

About...

> "it's also tedious to just repeat return base.Method();[...]"

...I would say that Visual Studio auto-generates this code for you meaning that it's worth the effort (overriding to apply new attributes).

In fact, it's a core design decision in .NET languages since reflection on attributes provides the method [`Type.GetCustomAttributes(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwc6ew1d) and it has an overload which accepts an input parameter called `inherit` and see its description:

> inherit
>   Type: System.Boolean
>
> true to search this member's inheritance chain to find the attributes; otherwise, false. This parameter is ignored for properties
>   and events [...]

Anyway, I don't find it an *unclear* way of doing that, since attributes are an implementation detail and this is why you require polymorphism to decorate an inherited member.

Maybe you're looking for something like this (*I've invented new C# syntax!*):

```
[AttributeA]
public metadataoverride int MethodA();
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you should call the method indirect.
Make a wrapper method that does all base code that should not be overridden:

```
private int MethodInternal() {

    // do common stuff here
    // original body of Method()

    return Method();
}
```

The body of `Method()` in the base class is empty, it's just there for the possibility to inject code.

This makes the call of `return base.Method()` in derieved classes unnecessary.

**Example:**

*Base class*

```
public virtual int Method()
{
    // empty
}
```

*Derived class A*

```
[AttributeA]
public override int Method()
{
    // no return base.Method() required
    return ???
}
```

Comment: I fail to understand the answer provided. Care to add some code? Thank you

Comment: I see now, but the client would still be able to override the Method() body and add code, which is something I'd rather avoid, as I wrote.

Comment: @joe This is like implementing a marker method to just decorate it with an attribute... I believe it's not a good design decision :(

Comment: Well, that's the intention of a virtual method. In my example, the base class method is empty, so it doesn't matter if anyone does not call `base.Method()`.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: If injecting the attribute is the only intention of the method (instead of implementing some additional code), then the design is completely wrong. In this case I suggest to assign the attribute to the derieved class as Jon Skeet mentioned.

Comment: @joe I don't find completely wrong. There're a lot of situations where you need to do that. For example, you've a data contract and base class has its properties without [DataMember(Name = "someProperty")] but an inherited class requires that some property should be part of serialized object. You'll override the whole property to add DataMemberAttribute...